# Using default camera application in Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera

I have a fragment which takes up the whole screen. Within this fragment I would like to enable the camera feature using the default camera application, rather than create a custom camera. I only want the camera to take up half the screen, below which I have buttons and other text. How can I do this?

Comment: have you try anything?

Comment: You have to make Custom Camera. As If you use Intent for Camera then you will get a full screen by default. You cannot use it. You want something like facebook uses in Messenger.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

Answer (score 1):

You have to make Custom Camera. As If you use Intent for Camera then you will get a full screen by default. You cannot use it. You want something like facebook uses in Messenger. Try this. This camera is in a Fragment. Replace the Fragment where required. Divide device height of surface view and fragment view.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample.You can use default camera app,
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/

Answer (score 0):

`Default android` cam app will take `full screen` `cant` use half screen for taking images.

For this `half screen` with `cam view` and `half with your widgets` you have to create your own cam view you can use this open source [**library**](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage) for this.